# Edit street view 360degree image title after upload

Tags: street-photography, 360-panorama, google-photos

I'm testing the 360degrees photos with the Samsung Galaxy Gear 360.

With my first panorama image upload to street view I see that the image title is "SAMSUNG" (above my name).

How can I edit that to mention the location name instead? And how can I avoid that happening in future panorama uploads through the Google Street View app?

Comment: Link to image in question would be helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about labeling photos within the google app, not about producing the photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem within Google Maps App under Android and for info that doesn't work with the dekstop version of google maps